# the number greater than or equal to ten million, using NumberFormatter Precision

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

here is my code

```
extension Float {
    func decimalString(maxPrecision: UInt) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = Int(maxPrecision)
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? ""
    }
}
```

but there is a problem

```
let a: Float = 12345678.1
print("\(a.decimalString(maxPrecision: 2))")
```

print 12,345,680， but 12,345,678.1 is expected
what's wrong!?!

Comment: Use a `Double` instead, `Float` is not precise enough.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`Double` represents a 64-bit floating-point number.
`Float` represents a 32-bit floating-point number.

So `Double` is more precise, use this code instead:

```
extension Double {
    func decimalString(maxPrecision: UInt) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = Int(maxPrecision)
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? ""
    }
}

let a: Double = 12345678.1
print("\(a.decimalString(maxPrecision: 2))") // 12,345,678.1
```